# More than 2 ORDER BY in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out if there can be more than two ORDER BY's in a single query, instead of having multiple queries. For some reason every time I include a third 'ORDER BY' it does not work on any column I choose.

***Here is my code (Single Query For Each):***

[image: First Code Image]

***This is what I am trying to do (This includes a Customer Order By):***

[image: What I am Trying To Do]

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you !

Comment: Please paste code in to the question using the appropriate formatting tools.

Comment: next time post it as a code, and to answer your question when ordering multiple cases, separate it in commas no need for more order by keyword

Comment: Alright thank you. Sorry this was my first time posting on here. I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN .... END ASC, Col1,Col2 ....
```

Separate multiple columns by comma instead of adding `ORDER BY` for each column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customers]
ORDER BY [ContactTitle] ASC,[Region] ASC,[ContactName] DESC,[Country] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like following: 
Multiple order by clause is not required.

Select * from [tablename] 
order by colum1,column2,column3